# MBP 2011 - GPU is hardware disabled - Black screen with MBR/BIOS mode on Windows 10

Tags: windows, bootcamp, gpu

So I had the GPU permanently disabled by a repair place and with a GPT install Windows, I can't use the sound & brightness slider. The fix is booting as a MBR/BIOS disk install but when I try to attempt it, all I'm getting is a black screen?

Is it because it's trying to use the AMD chip still? Does anyone know the fix for this?